# How to find duplicate number in a list using recursive in python?

Tags: python

I have tried following code, its only returning true or false,I just want to return which element is repeated but using only recursive approach only. Can anyone help me out please?

```
def check(myList):
    if len(myList) <= 1:
        return False
    if myList[0] == myList[1]:
        return True
    if check([myList[0]] + myList[2:]):
        return True
    if check(myList[1:]):
        return True
    return False



print(check([1,2,2,3,4]))
Sample output: 2
```

Comment: Sorry, you can’t change a question, which has received several answers, to a completely problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should return the repeated element:

```
def check(myList):
    if len(myList) <= 1:
        return None
    if myList[0] == myList[1]:
        return myList[0]
    return check(myList[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change last calling

```
def check(myList):
    if len(myList) <= 1:
        return False
    if myList[0] == myList[1]:
        return myList[0]
    return check(myList[1:])


print(check([1,2,2,3,4]))
# Sample output: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach unlike the other answers, prints all duplicates and not just the first one found.

```
def check(myList):
    if len(myList) <= 1:
        return # No need for False, just return.
    if myList[0] == myList[1]:
        print(myList[0], end = ' ')
    return check(myList[1:])
check([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]) # No need to use check in print()
```

When run this outputs:

```
2 3
```